# Como hacer llamado a dos procedimientos almacenados?

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedure

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer dos llamados a diferentes procedimientos almacenados en SQLServer desde PHP, los dos procedimientos almacenados se encuentran en una misma instancia de base de datos.

El siguiente es mi archivo PHP principal:

```
?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $param = $_POST['param'];   
    switch($param) {
        case '1': 
                $query = array();
                include './db/connect.php';
                $USER = $_POST['user'];
                $sql = "{call StoreProcedure()}";           
                $params = array($USER);
                $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
                if ( $stmt === false) {
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
                }
                $query = [];
                $lastName = '';
            
                while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt) ) {
                    if(strcmp($lastName, $row['Name']) != 0) {
                    $query[] = [
                        "Name"      => $row['Name'], 
                        "Position"  => $row['Position'], 
                        "Office"    => []
                    ];

                    $lastName = $row['Name'];
                }

                $indice = count($query) - 1;
                if($indice < 0) {
                    die('Error: Error attach Name');
                }
                $query[$indice]["Office"][] = [
                    "Salary" => $row['Salary'],
                    "Office" => utf8_encode ($row['Office']),               
                ];
                }
                sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);       
                sqlsrv_close($conn);

                $json = [
                    "success"=> count($query) > 0 ? true : false,
                    "data"=>$query
                ];

        break;

  }
```

Realmente soy nuevo en PHP y en este caso requiero hacer llamados a dos procedimientos almacenados diferentes.

Comment: ¿Qué dificultad o error tienes para llamar al segundo procedimiento?

Comment: @jachguate Ningún error, si te fijas ni si quiera estoy llamando el segundo procedimiento, solo llamo el primero

Comment: Eso puedo verlo, pero, voy a que tu pregunta me parece incompleta. Dices que quieres llamar a un segundo, no especificas si hay algún error en el código que publicas, ni el código muestra esa segunda llamada, ni dices cual es la dificultad para añadirla....

Comment: @jachguate Es correcto lo que dices, por eso en mi pregunta me refiero a "Como...."  en forma de adverbio interrogativo, en fin, lo que requiero es como puedo hacer dos llamados a diferentes procedimientos almacenados

Comment: El segundo procedimiento depende del primero? Por qué no lo llamas de la misma forma que llamas al primer proceidmiento?

Comment: Generalmente, llamas uno, procesas sus resultados y luego llamas al siguiente, siempre con `sqlsrv_query`.

Comment: @Bicho Así es, el segundo procedimiento depende del primero. Puedes aportarme un ejemplo como respuesta para darle validez